# What language to use for a keyboard simulation?

Tags: windows

I want to create a small application for windows that

1. can simulate keyboard presses and button clicks while in background
2. has Optical Character Recognition

I have programmed a few things in the past but never a windows application, so i don't know what language is best for that thing.

I don't need a complete Tutorial for how to do it, i just want a hint what language may be the best for it.

Greetings
Hithfaeron

Comment: what do you mean by " simulate keyboard presses and button clicks"

Comment: You will not be able to code OCR alone, because it is too complicated. You will have to use already made OCR library, and this may dictate the language you would have to use.

Comment: I mean that while the programm is in the background it should simulate specific keys to be pressed while no one is physically touching the keyboard @Akhil Surapuram

Comment: I know that i need to use such a library, i just dont know for what languages they already exist, so i asked here @Dialecticus

Comment: without pressing keys you want to program / vedio kind of mouse and keyboard kye stimulation?

Comment: I just want the programm to run in the background while i have a game open and to perform simple actions like walk there and click there, while i am away (single player, i dont want to cheat xD)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hie,

you can use any language with which you are comfortable with.

you can use c , c++ , Java , JS (Node) , python .... etc

Most of the common languages are supported in all modern OS's.

**For the this you want you achieve is to make your program is to listen for keyboard and mouse events, which any programming language does by interacting with the kernel**

Answer (score 0):

Eventhough I don't know what you meen exactly by Optical charcter recognition you can create a windows app like that one with nearly any common language. I've actually created a .dll that is capable of simulating a keyboard at a very decent speed (up to 3000 words per minute) with visual basic. I'ts a very basic language but as I did it implementing the user32.dll library in the code it's actually very easy to use. Would you like that I shared it with you that way you don't have to worry about the coding itself as it's very tedious and repetitive.